# Cordova App - Multiple Application Android:Name

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, cordova-plugins, android-build

I am attempting to use two Cordova plugins that of course both need the Application Android:name to be setup.

Plugins:
https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-cordova and 
https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin

Following other similar posts I created a MainApplication file and tried to extend the two plugins into the new public class. I'm amateur at this so I'm sure I am doing something wrong since I am getting the following error message when trying to build.

```
MainApplication.java:8: error: class CleverTapPlugin is public, should be declared in a file named CleverTapPlugin.java
public class CleverTapPlugin extends Application {

MainApplication.java:12: error: class ParsePushApplication is public, should be declared in a file named ParsePushApplication.java
public class ParsePushApplication extends CleverTapPlugin {

MainApplication.java:4: error: ParsePushApplication is already defined in this compilation unit
import github.taivo.parsepushplugin.ParsePushApplication;

MainApplication.java:5: error: CleverTapPlugin is already defined in this compilation unit
import com.clevertap.cordova.CleverTapPlugin;
```

Here is my MainActivity file:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Application;
import github.taivo.parsepushplugin.ParsePushApplication;
import com.clevertap.cordova.CleverTapPlugin;


public class CleverTapPlugin extends Application {

}

public class ParsePushApplication extends CleverTapPlugin {

}

public class MainApplication extends ParsePushApplication {

}
```

It seems my MainActivity is being called correctly in the build, since I am getting these error messages but I'm sure I did something wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to extend that plugin? I mean, you only need to add that plugin and use it inside your html.

Comment: @JorgeManuelBello yes normally that would be correct for plugin but both of these plugins seem to cause native crashes or do not track activity properly if they are not added in Application android:name so I need to extend them to get both working properly.

Comment: Well, error says you need to declare each class in separate files, anyway, plugins extends cordova class and implement special methods. So if you plan to extend those class my guess is you need to extends that class and implement those methods, and again add those new files to that plugin xml

Answer (score 0):

According to the CleverTap Android documentation, if you are using your own Application class you can call `ActivityLifecycleCallback.register(this);` before your `super.onCreate()` in your class.

Also if you’d like to use your own activity lifecycle listener, please update it to incorporate the following code:

```
application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(
        new android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
                CleverTapAPI.setAppForeground(true);
                try {
                    CleverTapAPI.getInstance(application).event.pushNotificationEvent(activity.getIntent().getExtras());
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    // Ignore
                }
                try {
                    Intent intent = activity.getIntent();
                    Uri data = intent.getData();
                    CleverTapAPI.getInstance(application).pushDeepLink(data);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
                try {
                    CleverTapAPI.getInstance(application).activityResumed(activity);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
                try {
                    CleverTapAPI.getInstance(application).activityPaused(activity);
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
            }
        }
);
```

For more information you can check out the following links -

[CleverTap Documentation - Advanced Topics](https://support.clevertap.com/docs/android/advanced-topics.html)

[CleverTap Documentation - Getting Started](https://support.clevertap.com/docs/android/getting-started.html)